# Is it appropriate to use "esteemed felicity" while introducing someone?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it appropriate to use "esteemed felicity" while introducing someone. For example:

> It is with esteemed felicity that I introduce Mr. Dan Thomas......

**Felicity** means *happiness*.
**Esteemed** means *respected*.

Doesn't **respectful** **happiness** sound weird?

I also noticed **esteemed felicity** being used in different context:

> All that was esteemed felicity here, is totally withdrawn.

What does this mean?

Comment: *esteemed felicity* means that your felicity is somehow esteemed. But Mr Dan Thomas is the one who is esteemed and you are happy to be introducing him.

Comment: No.  Sounds like thesaurus-induced gobbledygook.

Comment: Yes, but only if coupled with "and the deepest possible satisfaction."

Comment: How ostentatious are you trying to be?

Answer (score 1):

1. If Mr. Dan Thomas says of you, *the soon-to-be introducer*, before you introduce Mr. Dan Thomas,

> I, Mr. Dan Thomas, esteem your felicity most highly.

Then you might say afterward, during your introduction of Mr. Dan Thomas, with some justification (and a similar amount of humor),

> It is with esteemed felicity that I introduce Mr. Dan Thomas.

Otherwise, you're not likely to say that, because what is being respected (esteemed) is *the speaker's* happiness, not Mr. Dan Thomas.

2. 'Esteem' has the somewhat archaic or at least rarely used meaning of

> To account, consider, think, hold (a thing to be so and so).

So,

> All that was esteemed felicity here, is totally withdrawn.

might mean

> All that was considered felicity here is totally withdrawn.

Of the last, note that, on the face of it, the sentence contains an odd sequence of tenses ("was...is"), but there are contexts where that sequence makes sense.

Comment: Of course Mr Thomas' wife's name may be *Felicity*, who is accompanying him. Then it might be *It is with the esteemed Felicity that I present Mr Thomas*.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply wrong, because you cannot go from 'esteemed' meaning 'respectED' to esteemed meaning 'respectFUL', just to make the sentence work, in your head.  As written, it is the happiness that is being respected.